# Using Regex to match a path in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to use Powershell's Regex to match a specific string in a path. I then want to pipe that into Get-FileHash and get the MD5 hashes of all the files.

The path can change, depending on where the user has these files. So for instance, it can be

`C:\Program Files\StackOverflow\Powershell\Regex`

or

`C:\StackOverflow\Powershell\Regex`

I want to make it so that only the `Regex` portion is selected which I can then `-Recurse` and pipe into `Get-FileHash`. Also please note that there can be subfolders inside of Regex (for instance: `/Regex/Folder1` and `/Regex/Folder2`)

I can't quite get how to go about it. Please help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex is not needed. There's [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.1) that parses paths and returns desired sections.

For example (this is on MacOS, should work the same on Windows)

```
PS >pwd
/Users/myHomeDir

PS >pwd | split-path -leaf
myHomeDir
```

Also, a string that contains a path can be processed. Like so,

```
$p = "C:\Program Files\StackOverflow\Powershell\Regex"
split-path -leaf $p
Regex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern using named capture group 'path'

```
(?i)^(?<path>.+?(?:\\|\/)Regex)(?:(?:\\|\/)+.*)?$
```

If you need case-senstive matches, just remove the `(?i)` at the very beginning.

The pattern is aware of / and \ as path separator (including end of path). The rest of the path is not captured (?:)

For full explanation and samples see: https://regex101.com/r/xxaJzY/1/

Then use it the following way:

```
$folderName   = 'Regex'
$regexPattern = "(?i)^(?<path>.+?(?:\\|\/)$folderName)(?:(?:\\|\/)+.*)?$" 

<some other code>

$path = [regex]::Match($item, $regexPattern).Groups['path'].Value
```